# Angular 6: Render Nested JSON in a table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mdbootstrap, primeng-table

I have a nested JSON structure which needs to be represented in a table. 
The structure is:

```
students = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Ram",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "name": "Maths",
        "exams": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "exam1",
            "score": "90"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "exam2",
            "score": "80"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "name": "English",
        "exams": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "exam1",
            "score": "95"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "exam2",
            "score": "85"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": "101",
        "name": "Maths",
        "exams": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "exam1",
            "score": "80"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "exam2",
            "score": "90"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "102",
        "name": "English",
        "exams": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "exam1",
            "score": "85"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "exam2",
            "score": "95"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am using **p-table** from *pringng*. I need to have a outlook of table as follows:

[image: Sample Table Layout]

Could anyone please share their experiences in rendering nested json.

I have already tried nested tables and nested loops in div but the layout messed up big time.

**Sample code with p-table(primeng):**

```
<p-table #dt [value]="students" [responsive]="true"  [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" 
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,25,50]" [autoLayout]="true" [globalFilterFields]="['name']" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px" frozenWidth="300px" >
<ng-template pTemplate="header">

  <tr class="table-header">
    <th style="width:18%" class="table-header-column" >
      <span>Student Name</span>
    </th>
    <th style="width:8%" class="table-header-column"  rowspan="2">
      Subject
    </th>
    <th style="width:6%" class="table-header-column"  rowspan="2">
      Marks
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-header">
    <th>
        <input placeholder="Search Student" pInputText size="25"  type="text"
        (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')">
    </th>

  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-student>
  <div *ngFor="let subject of student.subjects; index as i" class="table-cell-color">
    <tr *ngFor="let exam of subject.exams; index as j" class="table-cell-color">      
          <td>{{student.name}}</td>
          <td>{{subject.name}}</td>
          <td>{{exam.score}}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output for Primeng]

**Sample of mdbTable with mdbBootstrap:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" mdbTable mdbTableScroll scrollY="true" scrollX="true" >
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-header">
      <th  >Student Name</th>
      <th >Subject</th>
      <th >Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let student of students" >
        <div *ngFor="let subject of student.subjects;">
            <div *ngFor="let exam of subject.exams; index as i">
                <td >{{student.name}}</td>
                <td >{{subject.name}}</td>
                <td >{{exam.name}}</td>
            </div>
        </div>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output for MdbBootstrap]
Would be great if someone can share their thoughts. I am open to switch to any other library if needed.

Comment: A working demo where I can test/run your code

Comment: I don't have snippet to share it. Could you please refer the JSON and try it out. All I need is the table structure as shared in the sample image. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: You're asking for a library recommendation and also asking people to write source code for you. Both are off topic here. Please update your question to show what you have tried so far, and what you're having difficulties with.

Comment: yes agreed with him at least you have to try!

Comment: Updated the question with code references

Comment: Please use ng-container. If you are able to add a snippet with some sample data, I can help you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what else can I add? I have already shared my html, and sample JSON used for rendering the html.

Comment: @AlexisToby - Thanks a lot for your suggestion :-) I replaced div with ng-container to loop, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Anamika Resolved?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale -- yes